# Need script syncing/matching time stamp of directory between local and remote host

Tags: linux

I Have a backup tool, which copies Directory from host A and keeps in host B.
This directory contains sub directories and files in it.
After copying this directory and its sub directories and files time stamp is showing current date. Its not showing original time stamp in host A.

Everyday this tool copies directory from host A and keeps in host B.
I have a script which copies time stamp from source directory and matches with destination directory. But this script only works locally.

```
#!/bin/bash
# change timestamp accordingly to original directory of files
BASE_OLD=/testing/etc
BASE_NEW=/tmp/etc
cd $BASE_OLD
find . -printf '%P\n' |
while read fname
do
TS=$(stat -c '%Y' "${BASE_OLD}/${fname}")
TIMESTAMP=$(date -d @${TS})
touch -m -d "${TIMESTAMP}" "${BASE_NEW}/${fname}"
echo "${BASE_NEW}/${fname}"
done
```

I need a script to ssh to host A and match the time stamp with directory host B.

Answer (score 2):

We're not a script writing service, I would imagine though that you could hack something up with ssh.

My suggestion would be to use a tool that copies the timestamps correctly and to that end I would suggest using [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

In particular the `-t` switch

> -t, --times                 preserve modification times

note that the `-a` switch includes `-t`

> -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)

so for example

```
rsync -avz /testing/etc user@example.com:/home/backup
```

should copy files from your local machine to the remote machine preserving the timestamps.